# formatException was unhandled

Tags: c#

I'm working with C# windows application 2010 express. 
here I have 3 textBoxes for total fee, amount paid, due amount. Total fee should be get from DB and amount paid should be entered by user and due amount should be calculated by the system. This is my scenario. I done the 1st part that means I filled the total fee column.
but the 2nd and 3rd part giving me an exception called "formatException was unhandled Input string was not in a correct format." Actually I'm getting this error when I'm erasing the amount paid value which I entered. It means in practical use I'll not able to erase that value in case user entered the wrong value. so please go through my code and correct it.

This my code:-

```
 private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox5.Text = "";
        int due = 0;
        due = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        if (textBox5.Text == null)
        {
            textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
        }
        else
        {

            textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(due);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `SimpleType.TryParse`

```
 decimal amount,fees,due;

 decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text,out amount);
 decimal.TryParse(textBox4.Text,out fees);

 due = amount - fees;

 textBox5.Text= due.ToString("N");
```

Method `SimpleType.TryParse` returns `true` if *string* is converted successfully; otherwise returns `false`.

For instance,

```
if(decimal.TryParse(textBox3.Text,out amount))
  //Valid
else
 //Invalid input
```

Answer (score 0):

when you pass empty or non numerical string to `Convert.ToInt32` you will get format exception.The string should be numerical.I think the text on textbox3 or textbox4 is either having a empty string or is not numerical

Use Int32.TryParse Instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should only allow Numerical values in `textBox3` and `textBox4` because `Convert.ToInt32` requires to have numerical values only.

I recommend you to use **`Int32.Parse()`**, since *it allows you more fine-grained control over the situation when the user enters in invalid input.*

And **`TryParse` will be the best since it always handles exceptions by itself.**

```
due = Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out amount) - 
      Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out fees);
```

Comment: Int32.TryParse is a safer option, IMO.

Comment: @user1724557 If one of the answers worked for you, don't forget to select it as the answer by clicking the checkmark