# Handling a FormatException was unhandled error

Tags: c#, regex

Currently, I have a textbox for input and label for output. Now, I'm working on arithmetic operators. I want to process numbers regardless of their operators.(e.g., Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division). Example: if I type 2*3 in the textbox, the answer will be displayed in the label.

Im using **contain**,**regex** and **split**; however, it's not working. It gives an error

> FormatException was Unhandled, Input string was not in the  correct format.

Here's my code:

```
namespace Windows
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);//error here
         string s = textBox1.Text;
         string seps = @"(\t)|(\n)|(\+)|(-)|(\*)|(/)|(\()|(\))";
         string[] tokens = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, seps);

         foreach (string token in tokens)
            label.Text = token;

         if (textBox1.Text.Contains("*")==true)
         {
            int num2 = num * num;
            label.Text = Convert.ToString(num2);
         }
      }

      public void CalcLexer(String str)
      {
         // Regex.Split(str, @"(?=[-+*/])|(?<=[-+*/])");
      }
   }
}
```

Can someone help me to fix this? Thank you so much in advace.

Comment: `2*3` is not a number, so `Convert.ToInt32` will throw that exception.

Comment: What is the value of `textBox1.Text`? Is it `2*3`? This is obviously not a valid integer. And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Sir it depends if what number and operator the user wants to input in textbox

Comment: It is better to comment the line with Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), because for sure it will throw an Exception in case of '2*3'

Comment: @Bluprints That's the point. `2*3` is not a valid integer, but `6` is. You can't parse this string as a valid integer.

Comment: Sir,still it gives the same error

Comment: @SonerGönül Sir, is there a way to handle this? Can you provide example sir? Im still a newbie at C#

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+math+expression+library

Comment: Sir is this the only way to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatException was unhandled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756879/formatexception-was-unhandled)

Comment: Are you looking to only solve single operations, or multiples?  For example, should your program be able to solve `5-1*2`?

Comment: @Namfuak Yes sir...That's what I need

Comment: Do you have any idea about that sir? I know my code is wrong.

Comment: You should start by reading each character and dividing your input string into numbers, operators, and parenthesis, then figuring out how to do each operation in the correct order according to PEMDAS.  I don't remember all the details of doing it through tokenization, but I'm sure there are some examples of it in google.  That said, if you aren't doing this as a learning project I'd recommend getting a library that handles it instead and save yourself the hassle.

Comment: Sir, what do you mean by library?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the string with the operators still in it:

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);//error here
```

At this point you'd still have the formula (2*3), not an individual number (2). You need to convert the numbers after you've split the string and confirmed that the 'token' is a number and not an operator.

Note that Convert.ToInt32 is designed to throw an exception if the given text is not a number. You could use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want it to tolerate the operators and not throw the exception.

Comment: sir, If you would mind, can you show the codes what it looks like? Using my above code?